# How to load external file when using LOAD CSV in neo4j?

Tags: csv, neo4j

I know that we can use

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///nodes.csv' AS row
```

in Neo4j, but seems the default folder is import directory under current Neo4j DB. If the DB is under disk D, how can I load the csv file under disk E using LOAD CSV (on Windows)? I have tried `'file:///e:/XXX.csv'`, `'file:e:/xxx.csv'`. None of them can works...

Answer (score 5):

You'll find a setting in neo4j.conf like this

```
# This setting constrains all `LOAD CSV` import files to be under the `import` directory. Remove or uncomment it to
# allow files to be loaded from anywhere in filesystem; this introduces possible security problems. See the `LOAD CSV`
# section of the manual for details.
dbms.directories.import=import
```

If you remove this/comment it, Neo4j should allow loading files from anywhere in the system

Comment: or you can set that directory to whatever your source is